# String assignment by reference/copy?

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain the behavior

**Scenario-1**

```
str = "hello"
str1 = str
puts str #=> hello
puts str1 #=> hello

str1 = "hi"
puts str1 #=> hi
puts str #=> hello
```

Here, changing the value of `str1` has no effect on the value of `str`.

**Scenario-2**

```
str = "hello"
str1 = str
str1.gsub! "hello", "whoa!"
puts str1 #=> whoa
puts str #=> whoa
```

Shoudn't the `gsub!` effect only the `str1`? Why is it changing `str`? If `str1` just holds the reference to `str`, then why did the value not change in **Scenario-1**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look below carefully:

***Scenario-1***

```
str = "hello"
str1 = str
puts str #=> hello
puts str1 #=> hello
p str.object_id #=>15852348
p str1.object_id #=> 15852348
```

In the above case `str` and `str1` holding the reference to the same object which is proved by the `object_id`. Now you use the local variable `str1` in the below case to hold a new object `"hi"`,which is also proved by the two different `object_id`s.

```
str1 = "hi"
puts str1 #=> hi
puts str #=> hello
p str.object_id  #=> 15852348
p str1.object_id #=> 15852300
```

**Scenario-2**

[`String#gsub!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) says:

> *Performs the substitutions of String#gsub in place, returning str, or nil if no substitutions were performed. If no block and no replacement is given, an enumerator is returned instead.*

```
str = "hello"
str1 = str
str1.gsub! "hello", "whoa!"
puts str1 #=> whoa
puts str #=> whoa
p str.object_id #=>16245792
p str1.object_id #=>16245792
```

Comment: Does this hold true for everything?  Everything is an object and everything is assign by reference?  Including other things that are normally primitives in other languages such as integers or floats?

Answer (score 0):

In variable assignment, it has no effect whether there was a variable with the same name, and if so, what value it was. In scenario-1, `str` is finally assigned `str1 = "hi"`, and whatever happened to it before that is irrelevant. Scenario-1 is the same as the following without `str1 = str`.

```
str = "hello"
str1 = "hi"
```

In Scenario-2, `str` and `str` are referring to the same string. If you change that via one of the variables pointing to that string, then when you call it via the other variable, it refers to the same changed string.